# Problem reading rotation on A-Frame enviroment

Tags: aframe

this is my first post here:

I would like to know where users are looking at when using a-frame. I'm now using the rotation listener component to know that. Something like:

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('rotation-listener', {
        tick() {
            const newValue = this.el.getAttribute('rotation');
            const stringCoords = AFRAME.utils.coordinates.stringify(newValue);
            if (this.lastValue !== stringCoords) {
                this.el.emit('rotationChanged', newValue);
                this.lastValue = stringCoords;
            }
        },
    });
    camera[0].addEventListener('rotationChanged', e => {
        console.log('Rotation: ', e.detail);
    });
}
```

But I have one issue, I have modified on look-controls the yawobject.rotation.y and the pitchobject.rotation.x and apply a 0,25 factor to get a lower sensitivity and look around more slow.

The problem is that when I get the values of the rotation variable on console.log shows me the correct value but divided by 0,25. This is an issue because on Y axis there is a cap on 90 and -90 (you reach that cap before the true cap is), so i can't obtain all the values correctly.

How can I solve that? Creating a new variable rotationdat which makes the correct calculation, without the 0,25? And then reading that variable on the rotation-listener component? I have done this but I don't know if it is correct:

```
onMouseMove: function (evt) {
          var direction;
          var movementX;
          var movementY;
          var pitchObject = this.pitchObject;
          var previousMouseEvent = this.previousMouseEvent;
          var yawObject = this.yawObject;
          var rotationdat = [0,0,0];

          // Not dragging or not enabled.
          if (!this.data.enabled || (!this.mouseDown && !this.pointerLocked)) { return; }

          // Calculate delta.
          if (this.pointerLocked) {
            movementX = evt.movementX || evt.mozMovementX || 0;
            movementY = evt.movementY || evt.mozMovementY || 0;
          } else {
            movementX = evt.screenX - previousMouseEvent.screenX;
            movementY = evt.screenY - previousMouseEvent.screenY;
          }
          this.previousMouseEvent.screenX = evt.screenX;
          this.previousMouseEvent.screenY = evt.screenY;
// Calculate rotation.
      direction = this.data.reverseMouseDrag ? 1 : -1;
      yawObject.rotation.y += movementX * 0.002 * this.data.mouseSpeedFactor * direction;
      pitchObject.rotation.x += movementY * 0.002 * this.data.mouseSpeedFactor * direction;
      pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max(-Math.PI / 2, Math.min(Math.PI / 2, pitchObject.rotation.x));

      //new rotation calculation calculo de rotacion
      yawObject.rotationdat.y += movementX * 0.002 * direction;
      pitchObject.rotationdat.x += movementY * 0.002 * direction;
      pitchObject.rotationdat.x = Math.max(-Math.PI / 2, Math.min(Math.PI / 2, pitchObject.rotationdat.x));
      rotationdat = (pitchObject.rotationdat.x, yawObject.rotationdat.y, 0);
    },
```

Thank you for read me!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simpler to acess the camera in the underlying `Threejs` layer instead of decomposing the `look-controls`.

Any `threejs` object has a [`getWorldQuaternion()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldQuaternion) method, which you can use to get the current "global" rotatation:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
    init: function() {
      this.text = document.querySelector("a-text"); // to display the angles
      this.tmpQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(); // to keep the current rotation
      this.tmpEuler = new THREE.Euler(); // we want euler angles, not quaternions
    },
    tick: function() {
      const camera = this.el.sceneEl.camera; // get the camera reference
      camera.getWorldQuaternion(this.tmpQuaternion); // get the 'global' rotation as a quaternion object
      this.tmpEuler.setFromQuaternion(this.tmpQuaternion, "YXZ"); // convert it to euler angles

      // get the yaw, pitch, and roll components, and display them as degrees
      const string = [
        THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(this.tmpEuler.x).toFixed(2),
        THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(this.tmpEuler.y).toFixed(2),
        THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(this.tmpEuler.z).toFixed(2)
      ].join(" ");
      this.text.setAttribute("value", string)
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene foo>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-text position="-0.5 1 -2.5" color="black"></a-text>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```